# How can I avoid Depsgraph rebuild times?

Tags: python, rendering, optimization, depsgraph

I have two objects (in collections) in the scene and I want to render only one of them programmatically (from Python). When I measure the rendering time, there is always overhead of Depsgraph build time.

```
import time
import bpy

bpy.app.debug_depsgraph_time = True

start = time.time()
print("Start: ",start, "s")

bpy.data.collections['B747'].hide_render=False
bpy.data.collections['B757'].hide_render=True
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

end = time.time()
print("End: ", end, "s")
print("Duration: ",end -start)
```

```
Start:  1687435725.4579306 s
Depsgraph built in 0.105444 seconds.
Depsgraph updated in 0.009703 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: 0.020573
Saved: '/tmp/output0001.exr'
 Time: 00:00.14 (Saving: 00:00.02)

Depsgraph updated in 0.008152 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: 0.023989
End:  1687435725.734076 s
Duration:  0.27614545822143555
```

As you can see, rendering + saving takes only 0.14 seconds while the whole duration of the code is 0.27 seconds.

When I comment out [`hide_render`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection.hide_render), there is no such overhead.

```
# bpy.data.collections['B747'].hide_render=False
# bpy.data.collections['B757'].hide_render=True
```

```
Start:  1687435918.4967954 s
Depsgraph built in 0.000358 seconds.
Depsgraph updated in 0.001326 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: -nan
Saved: '/tmp/output0001.exr'
 Time: 00:00.16 (Saving: 00:00.02)

Depsgraph updated in 0.008340 seconds.
Depsgraph evaluation FPS: 0.020629
End:  1687435918.680713 s
Duration:  0.18391752243041992
```

Here, we observe 0.02s overhead which is fine.

Now, I want to avoid this Depsgraph build time overhead due to `hide_render`.

What I tried is:

1. Move away method

   - Leave all the objects to be rendered and do not configure `hide_render` in the code.
   - Move the object away from the camera that I do not want to render in the image.

=> It still loads the textures of all the objects for each rendering, so the rendering takes more time.

2. Visibility method

   - Don't touch `hide_render`.
   - Turn off all the visibility parameters to False from [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.visible_camera)

=> Same as 1.

Is there a way that I do not reload all the objects per rendering without setting `hide_render`?

Comment: Hello, it looks like what you want isn't really achievable, modifying the scene data and not allowing it to rebuild itself will logically lead to incorrect rendering results